# メガメニューのトグルがうまく行かない

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

ヘッダーにメガメニューを実装しようとしています。

下記スニペットのような実装をしているのですが、

- 初めて.nav（または.nav__item）をホバーした場合はslideDownで開く
- .nav内でかつ.nav__itemを行き来する場合はfadeInとhideで切り替え
- .navのエリアから出た場合はslideUpで閉じる

ということがやりたいです。

.nav内にいる場合は.navに.is-activeを付与して
is-activeがあれば.nav__itemをfadeIn,hideする
なければ.nav__itemをslideDown,slideUpする

上記の考えで大丈夫だと思っていましたが、.navを出た際にis-activeが消えるより早くitemのhideが実行されてしまいました。

delayやsetTimeoutでタイミングをずらせば出来そうではありますが、
あまりそういうことはやりたくないと感じました。

何か良い実装方法はありますでしょうか。
ご回答のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

```js
$(function(){
  const $nav = $('.nav');
  const $item = $('.nav__item');

  $nav.hover(
    function(){
      $nav.addClass('is-active');
    },
    function(){
      $nav.removeClass('is-active');
    }
  );

  $item.hover(
    function (){
      const $this = $(this);
      if($nav.hasClass('is-active')) $this.find('.megamenu__body:not(:animated)').fadeIn();
      else $this.find('.megamenu__body:not(:animated)').slideDown();
    },
    function (){
      const $this = $(this);
      if($nav.hasClass('is-active')) $this.find('.megamenu__body:not(:animated)').hide();
      else $this.find('.megamenu__body:not(:animated)').slideUp();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}
.nav__item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav__item:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.megamenu {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.megamenu__body {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav__item">itemA
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="megamenu__body">contentA</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav__item">itemB
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="megamenu__body">contentB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回の場合イベントの伝播を制御しようとするとかえって複雑になりそうなので、月並みな方法ですが、 `is` メソッドで `$nav` がホバーされているかどうかを確認し、それを都度変数へ保存しておくという方法が代替として考えられます。

```
$(function() {
  const $nav = $('.nav');
  const $item = $('.nav__item');
  let isNavHovered = $nav.is(':hover');

  $item.hover(
    function() {
      const $megamenu = $(this).find('.megamenu__body').stop(true, true);
      if (isNavHovered) $megamenu.fadeIn();
      else $megamenu.slideDown();
      isNavHovered = $nav.is(":hover");
    },
    function() {
      if ($nav.is(":hover")) $(this).find('.megamenu__body').stop(true, true).hide();
      else $nav.find('.megamenu__body').stop(true, true).slideUp();
      isNavHovered = $nav.is(":hover");
    }
  );
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  const $nav = $('.nav');
  const $item = $('.nav__item');
  let isNavHovered = $nav.is(':hover');

  $item.hover(
    function() {
      const $megamenu = $(this).find('.megamenu__body').stop(true, true);
      if (isNavHovered) $megamenu.fadeIn();
      else $megamenu.slideDown();
      isNavHovered = $nav.is(":hover");
    },
    function() {
      if ($nav.is(":hover")) $(this).find('.megamenu__body').stop(true, true).hide();
      else $nav.find('.megamenu__body').stop(true, true).slideUp();
      isNavHovered = $nav.is(":hover");
    }
  );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav__item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav__item:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.megamenu {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.megamenu__body {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav__item">itemA
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="megamenu__body">contentA</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav__item">itemB
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="megamenu__body">contentB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is()と:hover、自分じゃ絶対思いつかない方法でした。ありがとうございました！